# How to remove new ArrayList<>?

Tags: java, android

I have try methods like remove, removeAll, delete. But all of these words is not available in android studio. What word should i used instead?

```
public List<ContactObject> receipt = new ArrayList<>();
receipt.add(new ContactObject(object.product_title, object.product_price,   
 object.img1, object.quantity));
```

I know how to add to the list receipt, but how to remove the data added?

Comment: receipt.remove(position);

Comment: They are (well, remove is), but you can't write a statement directly after a field declaration like that. Statements have to be in method/constructors. See http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/ArrayList.html

Comment: It's not *What word* It's *Which method*.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?  Remove one element?  Remove all elements?

Comment: The list `receipt` is `ContactObject` and the object you try to add is `ContactObject2`. If `ContactObject2` does not extend or implement `ContactObject`, this will not work.

Comment: is typo error, both is ContactObject

Comment: Also the list is declared as `receipt` and you add to `receipts`.

Comment: because it is display in a listview1 where you click the listview1, it will load another page where there is a listview2. However, when i'm loading listview2, there are remaining item that i have click in listview1 being display in listview2, it is like they are accumulating. Thats why i want to delete the list, so that everytime i click a new item in listview1, it display only that item in listview2

Comment: you can use receipt.clear() to clear the entire array list :) happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't add the new object directly, you can remove it like this:

```
List<ContactObject> receipts = new ArrayList<>();
ContactObject contactObject = new ContactObject(object.product_title, object.product_price,   
object.img1, object.quantity)
receipts.add(contactObject);
// Remove previous added object
receipts.remove(contactObject);
```

Answer (score 0):

The `remove()` of an `ArrayList` depends on the implementation of equals() method, in your case in `ContactObject`.

Invoking remove() then will solve your issue.

```
receipts.remove(contactObject);
```

Answer (score 0):

removeAll removes all the given objects and returns the state of the operation.while remove only remove the object that is currently provided.
In your case you want to remove a single object by

```
 yourarraylist.remove(yourobject);
```